# Adding items in an array to different array at certain index

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have two arrays

```
var array1 = [Doc 1, Doc 2, Doc 3]
var array2 = [Part 1, Part 2, Part 3]
```

I want to put items in array2 in array1 at certain index(between Doc 1 and Doc 2) like following:

```
[Doc 1, Part 1, Part 2, Part 3, Doc 2, Doc 3]
```

I know how to put an array into another array at certain index. But I'm not familiar with this kind of case. Is there any builtin method I can use in Swift? I can make my own algorithm but would like to know first if there's any built method for this case.

Comment: You say "I know how to put an array into another array at certain index". Do you mean you want a function that says "insert items from `array1` between items `y` and `z` in `array2`"? I don't think you'll find anything that specific in the standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
array1.insertContentsOf(array2, at: 1)
```